# I'm not sure how to fix this code. The first part is a loop (needs to be the first section) and I don't know how to close it

Tags: java

Ok so here is the code, and the first section is trying to keep rolling 2 dice until they add to 7 or 11, then continue the rest of the code. I can only get it to roll once, and if it is 7 or 11 the code stops.

```
import java.io.*;

public class JavaOlympics {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int die1, die2, total;
        // Continue loop until reaches a total of 7 or total of 11
        while (true) {
            die1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
            die2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 6);
            // Display the dice roll
            System.out.println("Die_1 = " + die1);
            System.out.println("Die_2 = " + die2);
            // Add the results
            total = die1 + die2;
            // Output total
            System.out.println("Total = " + total);
            System.out.println();
            // Break loop when total of 7 or 11 is reached
            if (total == 7 || total == 11)
                break;

            String s1, s2;
            // DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in); //deprecated
            BufferedReader dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            // Ask for string input
            System.out.println("Input two strings one by one");
            s1 = dis.readLine();
            s2 = dis.readLine();
            // Organize strings in alphabetical order
            System.out.println("\nStrings in alphabetical order");
            if (s1.compareTo(s2) <= 0) {
                System.out.println(s1);
                System.out.println(s2);
            } else {
                System.out.println(s2);
                System.out.println(s1);
            }
            // Count characters in the strings
            System.out.println("\nNo.of characters");
            System.out.println(s1 + " :: " + s1.length());
            System.out.println(s2 + " :: " + s2.length());

            // Convert strings between lowercase and uppercase
            System.out
                    .println("\nFirst String in Uppercase and Second String in Lowercase");
            System.out.println(s1.toUpperCase());
            System.out.println(s2.toLowerCase());

            String s;
            // DataInputStream dis2 = new DataInputStream(System.in); // deprecated
            BufferedReader dis2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
            // Request sentence input from user
            s = dis2.readLine();
            // Count number of spaces
            int space_count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    space_count++;
                }
            }
            // Output number of words
            System.out.println("Number of words = " + (space_count + 1));
            // Output number of characters and average characters per word
            System.out.println("Number of characters = " + (s.length()));
            System.out.println("Average number of characters/word = "
                    + (1.0 * (s.length() / space_count)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problems was extras "}", if question is ok... mark completed :-)

Answer (score 0):

> then continue the rest of the code

All of your code is enclosed in the `while` loop. When you `break` out of it, there is no more code to execute.

It would be much easier to see if you used sensible indentation.

To fix, you probably just need to move a closing brace.

Answer (score 0):

All your code is within the while loop, you have missed off a closed bracket where you need the loop to end

Answer (score 0):

what exactly do you want to do in your code. your code works fine, but it runs into a loop unless and until the value of the sum of 2 dice equals 11 or 7.

your entire code is in while loop. So from my understanding of your question, if you want the rest of your code to execute after the completion of while loop then just close while loop as follows

```
while(true)
{
die1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
die2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random()*6);
//Display the dice roll
System.out.println("Die_1 = " + die1);
System.out.println("Die_2 = " + die2);
//Add the results
total = die1 + die2;
//Output total
System.out.println("Total = " + total);
System.out.println();
//Break loop when total of 7 or 11 is reached
if (total == 7 || total == 11) break;
} // close your while loop here and remove one brace at the end of your class.
```

If my understanding is wrong you can correct me